# Skip the last task when the previous condition is true

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I want to skip the last task "- name: Fail if not in office hours" if my previous task "- name: get working office hours" condition is true.

What is happening is when my "get working office hours" condition is true the last task is not skipping.

I will be importing this playbook in AWX and scheduling a chain of jobs. I have two options. Either create a condition of the last task(Fail if not in office hours) and fail it or if the 2nd last task(get working office hours) runs successfully it should skip the last task so that other job gets triggered on the 2nd last task successful condition.

**Note: In AWX skipped tasks are not identified properly. The task should fail if condition not satisfied.**

My question might be confusing because I am trying different logics to make this playbook work. Hope you guys understand what I am asking.

- name: ansible date and time output
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: define ansible variable
  debug:
  var: ansible_date_time

  ```
      - name: Print msg variable
        debug:
                msg: "{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}"

      - name: Set variables
        set_fact:
                cur_time: "{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}"

      - name: Print Current time
        debug:
                msg:  "{{ cur_time }}"

      - name: get working office hours
        debug:
                msg: "Yes ! Current time is between office hours"
        when:  cur_time | int >= 7 and cur_time | int <= 19


      - name: Fail if not in office hours
        debug:
                msg: "No ! Current time is not between office hours"
        failed_when: cur_time | int < 7 and cur_time | int > 18
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`failed_when` executes when the provided expression evaluates `true`. Using 17 as an example, your playbook would evaluate as follows:

```yaml
cur_time: 17

- name: get working office hours
    debug:
            msg: "Yes ! Current time is between office hours"
    when:  17| int >= 7 and 17| int <= 19 # evaluates true


- name: Fail if not in office hours
    debug:
            msg: "No ! Current time is not between office hours"
    failed_when: 17| int < 7 and 17| int > 18 # evaluates false, does not fail
```

If you want to keep the same structure of your tasks, negate the final expression as such:

```yaml
 name: Fail if not in office hours
    debug:
            msg: "No ! Current time is not between office hours"
    failed_when: not (cur_time| int < 7 and cur_time| int > 18)
```

Result:

```yaml
PLAY [play] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print msg variable] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "18"
}

TASK [Set variables] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print Current time] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "18"
}

TASK [get working office hours] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Yes ! Current time is between office hours"
}

TASK [Fail if not in office hours] **************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "No ! Current time is not between office hours"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If I were you however, I would prefer to use an `assert` task to ensure we are in office hours, then we can continue with the playbook:

```yaml
- name: Set variables
  set_fact:
    cur_time: "{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}"

- name: Ensure we are running playbook within working hours
  assert:
    that: cur_time | int >= 7 and cur_time | int <= 19
    success_msg: "Yes ! Current time is between office hours"
    fail_msg: "No ! Current time is not between office hours"

# continue with the rest of your play as normal
```

This gives us (within working hours):

```yaml
PLAY [play] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print msg variable] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "18"
}

TASK [Set variables] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print Current time] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "18"
}

TASK [Ensure we are running playbook within working hours] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Yes ! Current time is between office hours"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And when outside of working hours:

```yaml
PLAY [play] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print msg variable] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": 1
}

TASK [Set variables] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print Current time] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": 1
}

TASK [Ensure we are running playbook within working hours] **************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "cur_time | int >= 7 and cur_time | int <= 19",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "No ! Current time is not between office hours"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I used the assert task and it worked perfectly. Really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Hey no problem glad I could help 0-)